# How can I obtain the list of values for a given key and add the list of values to a newly created list?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

So I'm going crazy with this one. This is for an assignment and can't seem to get this to work at all!!
I have the following HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Team>> teams;
```

(Team being another class to obtain the details of the teams)

What I need to be able to do is get the List of teams for the Key(String) from the above HashMap, and assign the List to a local variable I have declared:

`List<Team> results = teams.get(division)`;

But this is where I get stuck. I have no idea how I'm suppose to complete this task. 
As a further note "division" is the Key used in the HashMap. The ArrayList is a list of teams that belong to the division.

I have tried the below, which does not compile at all. Really not sure how I can get this to work!!

```
public void recordResult(String division, String teamA, String teamB, int teamAScore, int teamBScore)
 {
  List<Team> results = teams.get(division);
  for (String i : teams.keySet())
  {
     results = new ArrayList<Team>();
     results.add();

  }
```

}

**You can ignore the arguments after the "String division". These will be used later.

Comment: You need recursive here..

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the `entrySet()` of the Map. Now you can fetch *each* List for that specific key and proceed further. Something like:

```
for (Entry<String, ArrayList<Team>> entry : teams.entrySet()) {

   // extract the value from the key using `teams.get(entry.getKey())`

   // proceed further with the value obtained

}
```